# Flask request.form.get() returning TypeError/NoneType

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

HTML Code:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Astrotools - Planetary Hours Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Astrotools</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href = '#'>Planetary Hours Calculator</a></li>
    <li><a href = #>Tarot Astrology Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href = #>Graphic Declination Ephemeris (Coming Soon)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Planetary Hours Calculator</h2>
  <div>
    <form action="planetaryhours" method="POST">
      <label for="city">City:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id ="city" name="city"><br>
      <label for="region">Region:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="region" name="region"><br>
      <label for="month">Month (MM):</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="month" name="month">
      <label for="day">Day (DD):</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="day" name="day">
      <label for="year">Year (YYYY):</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="year" name="year">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id = "hours_section">
    <p>{{ cityname }}</p>
    <p>{{ year }}</p>
    <p>{{ month }}</p>
    <p>{{ day }}</p>
    <p>{{ dayminuteorder }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Python Code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import astral
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
from astral import LocationInfo
from astral.sun import sun
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/planetaryhours", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getinfo():
    #user inputs
    cityname = request.form.get('city')
    countryname = request.form.get('region')
    year = request.form.get('year')
    month = request.form.get('month')
    day = request.form.get('day'.)

    addtest = month + day

    return render_template("planetaryhours.html", cityname=cityname, countryname=countryname, year=year, month=month, day=day, addtest=addtest)
```

I can't figure out why my code isn't working and none of the solutions I'm seeing online are helping--I've been searching and googling since yesterday with no luck. I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to build an app to take user input to make a calculator, but every time I go to test my app I get some variation of a type error like these:

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'"
"TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'"

I am able to get the values from the form and simply display them on the page, but when I want to use them to do calculations in my python code is where I'm running into trouble. It keeps saying the input variables (month, day, and year) are NoneType and I'm not sure why because I can print the variables just fine and they show up on the HTML page. It's only when I try to add them or convert to int, then I get TypeError messages.

Is there a different way I should  be doing this with Flask?

BTW there is more code--that's the reason for all the installed packages at the top. The only thing holding the rest of the program up is the TypeError problem with the request.form.get() input variables for the month, day, and year.

Comment: Have you tried to check `request.form` content? It's obvious that it's missing both `'month'` and `'day'` keys and as you don't pass default value to `.get()` it returns `None` which causes exception later.

Comment: I have but when I use that I get a 400 Bad Request error. Where do I get month and day keys? Is it that I have to define a default value for the inputs in the HTML and then include that in the .get parentheses? I have tried that and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the request method was `POST` or `GET`, and only start trying to retrieve values from the form when its `POST`

```py
@app.route("/planetaryhours", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getinfo():

    # initialize all variables as empty strings
    # (I don't know the best way to do this, but I'm sure there is a better way)
    cityname = countryname = year = month = day = addtest = ''

    # check the method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # this only happens when the user submits a request from the form
        #user inputs
        cityname = request.form.get('city')
        countryname = request.form.get('region')
        year = request.form.get('year')
        month = request.form.get('month')
        day = request.form.get('day')

        addtest = month + day
    else:
        # you can also set variables beforehand
        year=2022

    return render_template("planetaryhours.html",
                           cityname=cityname,
                           countryname=countryname,
                           year=year,
                           month=month,
                           day=day,
                           addtest=addtest)
```

EDIT: I forgot to initialize all the variables used, so added those.